# Can I generate hash function providing inputs/outputs?

Tags: java, function, hash

I am not sure how to ask this question, but trying my best to elaborate it. Apologies for any confusions.

I am looking for some theoretical way, to generate a function based on certain inputs and outputs.

For example I need to store combinations of inputs for millions of string like below:

[image]

I want to avoid storing all such million records. Is there a way using which, I can once iterate through all input/output combinations, I can generate a function. So that the next time it comes to check again, I do not need to go through all million records, just a generated function **f(i)** can return me correct **Yes/No**.

[image]

Of course, I do not want to just keep all inputs in concatenated format because I am looking for space/time optimal solution.

Comment: Why do you think you have to iterate over all inputs for a lookup? Can't you just use a dictionary for fast look up? Also, you could keep only the keywords which will result to a `yes` , everything else would be automatically a `no`.

Comment: Can you store the key-value in a Map, or some key-value database like Redis?

Comment: From your given example, I guess the best you can do is to store all your input/output combinations in a `HashMap`. If there are only two possible outputs, it might be enough to store only those inputs that produce one of them (e.g. "Yes")  in a `HashSet` and just return the other one for everything that is not contained in the set.

Comment: It's in millions, hence I am trying to avoid even storing under Map/Dictionary.

Comment: Well, if the inputs don't have some property that makes it possible to calculate the mapping on the fly, you need to store it somehow.

Comment: @Hulk You are right, but I do not know if there is no guarantee that records with Yes or No will be few. Assume that both are nearly 50-50%.

Comment: If there *is* a hidden property that distinguishes the inputs, but it is not easy to formalize in code, you could try a deep-learning approach - that is, if you can live with the system getting it right *most*  of the time... this could then even handle unknown inputs. But that is certainly not easier and probably also not more efficient than just storing the full set of inputs if they are known in advance.